# iOS: simulate iPhone camera roll with zoom

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming

In my app I simulate camera roll of iPhone; 
I have a mainScrollView with all image, and for every image I have a srollView to zoom it. You know that you can zoom every page with an image, but is there a way to have all image with zoom at 1.5 (for example); when I open camera roll I want to see every image with a zoom (1.5 for example) is it possible? 
I try this:

```
for (int i = 0;i<13;i++){
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
        scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[scrollV viewWithTag:i + SCROLL_TAG];
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.35;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.35;
        [scrollView setZoomScale:1.35];
        [scrollView release];
    }
```

but this code zoom only first image, I don't know why!!!

Comment: scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[scrollV viewWithTag:i + SCROLL_TAG];
 what does this line do?

Comment: I have a scrollView for each image, then I set a tag for every scrollview; with this line of code, I set that "scrollView" is one of my scrollviews

Comment: ah and scrollV is the mainScrollView

Comment: if thats the case, then the instance created just above is superfluous isnt it? and so is the release..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that all you would possibly need is just this, because the alloc and the release at the end are merely superfluous. beyond that the code is pretty much straight forward.

```
for (int i = 0;i<13;i++){
        UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[scrollV viewWithTag:i + SCROLL_TAG];
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.35;
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.35;
        [scrollView setZoomScale:1.35];
    }
```

once you do this, try printing the zoomscale of one of these views outside the loop just to be sure.